# Using Mathematical Induction to prove Reversal of Strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The problem at hand:

Recall our recursive definition of the reversal of a string over $\Sigma$.

- Base case: $\epsilon^R=\epsilon$
- If $w \in \Sigma^*$ and $c \in \Sigma$, then $(wc)^R =cw^R$.

Use the definition above along with mathematical induction to prove the following: If $v,w$ are strings over $\Sigma$, then $(vw)^R= w^Rv^R$.

I'm honestly stumped and don't know where to begin. I've done mathematical induction on actual numbers but not on just variables like this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use ordinary induction on the length of the string.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: If you throw away fancy words like "induction" do you know how to solve this? Why might you expect this to be true if you came at it less rigorously?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it by induction on the structure of $w.$ The idea is to show that

1. The equation holds for $w=\epsilon$.
2. If the equation holds for $w'$ and $c$ is a character, then it holds for $w'c.$

Hopefully you can see how this implies it holds for any string $w$ by analogous reasoning to induction on $\mathbb N$.

(Alternatively as Lord Shark suggests in the comments, you can just think of it as ordinary induction on the length of $w.$ If $w=w'c,$ then $w'$ is a string shorter than $w.$)

The base case is easy. Then for the induction step we have $$(v w'c)^R = c(vw')^R=cw'^Rv^R=(w'c)^Rv^R$$ where the second equality uses the induction hypothesis and the other two use the definition of $R.$